# C++ check from where specified function/method was called

Tags: c++

Is it possible to somehow check from where specified function was called? e.g. get address responsible for calling it, or if I want to check if this function is called from "File.exe" or "Other.dll"? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I want to do it in my code(without any debugger..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on Windows, you probably could use functions provided in dbghelp library. I think you could use the [StackWalkEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn280332%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You can find an [example on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11132/Walking-the-callstack). It says:

> The usage of the class is very simple. For example if you want to
>   display the callstack of the current thread, just instantiate a
>   StackWalk object and call the ShowCallstack member:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "StackWalker.h"

void Func5() { StackWalker sw; sw.ShowCallstack(); }
void Func4() { Func5(); }
void Func3() { Func4(); }
void Func2() { Func3(); }
void Func1() { Func2(); }

int main()
{
  Func1();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can set a breakpoint you can examine the call stack.

Answer (score 2):

My first question would have to be: Why would you want to do this?

Having said that, there is absolutely no portable way to do this.  With GCC, and Clang to the best of my knowledge, you can use __builtin_return_address(0), but with Visual Studio (which I presume you are using, given exe/dll), I can't offer up any equivalent.

Normally if you are doing this, you need to look at your design, as there should be no reason to get the calling address unless you are writing, say, a trampoline function.

Answer (score 1):

As chmeee said, there is no portable method for doing this.  On Windows, there are a set of debugging functions (which you can use in your code) to accomplish it (in a way):  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679303(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

If it's your code, pass the caller's name as one of the parameters to the function.

Otherwise, there's no portable way to do this. And even the non-portable ways are not necessarily going to work exactly as you expect. Introspection is not C++'s thing.

Answer (score -2):

I generally throw a fake exception. It has worked in Java. (and C++ in my past years). 
Like

```
try {
    throw(new Exception());
}
catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The only other programmatic way I know of is to use Aspects (AOP).